# Alpine VM not saving after rebooting

Tags: alpine-linux

I did setup-alpine then installed busybox-extras. After I rebooted the VM, it reverted to the initial configurations.

Is it just for Alpine VM, or should I save it? I can't find any commands to save the  current config of Alpine VM.

Answer (score 4):

From the alpine-wiki you have to **shutdown** the virtual machine, then remove the Alpine ISO from the virtual optical drive.

Quote:
"...**Install Alpine on the virtual computer**

Follow the steps described in the Installation Handbook, just as if you installed Alpine on a real PC.
Tip: **Do not reboot your virtual box after the installation.** Rather, shut the virtual machine down, remove the Alpine ISO from the virtual optical drive, and then restart the virtual machine..."

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Install_Alpine_on_VirtualBox

Comment: Addicionally, when you have finished to install  busybox-extras you can create a snapshot on the running virtual machine.

Comment: VirtualBox menu > Machine > Take Snapshot

Comment: That is it really! Just remove the Alpine ISO from persistent storage and just let the VDI sit there.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue by trying to configure Alpine on Hyper V. I resolved choosing sys-mode during installation.

> **sys mode**
>
> This is a traditional hard-disk install (see link for details). Both
>   the boot system and your modifications are written to the hard disk,
>   in a standard Linux hierarchy.
>
> Note: The setup-alpine script handles installing Alpine in this mode,
>   too, when you supply a writable partition instead of "none", and
>   request mode "sys". By default, it will create three partions on your
>   disk, for /boot, /, and swap; however you can also partition your disk
>   manually.
>
> This mode may be used for desktops, development boxes, and virtual
>   servers.